# Issues with prompting for user input after displaying a cell of an array

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to write a small program that gathers a response from a user after each item in an array is printed to the screen.

I can print each item in the array like this:

```
string[] music = new string[4];
music[0] = "question 1";
music[1] = "question 2";
music[2] = "question 3";
music[3] = "question 4";

foreach (string j in music)
{
    Console.WriteLine(j);
}
```

But I'm not sure how to capture the user's input.

For example, after the user is shown "question 1," is there a way to break, and prompt a user input? This would occur for each item in the array.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "looped array?" It's unlikely that you'll get a good answer without formatting your question into paragraphs for readability, then perhaps offering an example (in pseudocode, or perhaps even clear sentences) of what you're hoping to accomplish.

Comment: Yeah, that is probably a good point.  Sorry, new to the site. What I meant was I am displaying elements of an array using a for loop. Each element of the array is a question, and I would like to prompt the user for an answer after. I am not sure if it is even possible. Like I said I am quite new to programming.

Comment: Does the edit I added improve the question at all? I cut out most of the filler and just asked what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: No problem, welcome to the site! It can definitely take some getting used to for how to ask questions, no worries. I've made a couple edits as well. I think your edited version was fine, but a lot of people are scared off by questions that start with a block of code. But yes, I have voted to reopen the question, and reversed my vote.

Comment: Just add Console.ReadLine after Console.WriteLine and program will stop and wait for user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to jump out of the loop, you can put that logic *in* the loop.

```
foreach (string j in music)
{
    Console.WriteLine(j);

    string read = Console.ReadLine(); // This blocks until the user presses 'enter'

    Console.WriteLine(read); // Just echo the response.
}
```

Of course, you could also call a separate method that gathers and processes the response, which might be a cleaner approach, depending on how much you need to do with them.

It really then depends on how you want to use the responses, and whether you want to look at them all at once, and I don't know if you've learned about the [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) type yet, but this could be a nice way to store mapped responses.

```
Dictionary<string, string> responses = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (string j in music)
{
    Console.WriteLine(j);

    string read = Console.ReadLine(); // This blocks until the user presses 'enter'

    responses[j] = read;
}
```

A non-dictionary alternative to that would be to use a `for` loop and have a second array of the same size that stores responses for each respective element in `music`.

The trouble, of course, with delaying the processing, is that you'd have to loop through the collection twice. Not a big deal at this size, but with a big collection, it could be. It's a good habit not to do that unless you have to.

---

After a bit of talking in comments, it sounds like this is what you're looking for.

```
string[] music = new string[4];
// ... populate music

string[] expectedResponses = new string[music.Length];
// ... populate expected responses

for (int i = 0; i < music.Length; i++)
{
    string j = music[i];
    string expectedResponse = expectedResponses[i];

    string actualResponse = Console.ReadLine();
    if(actualResponse == expectedResponse) // you might want to do something about casing here
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
    }
    else
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect.");
    }
}
```

Comment: The dictionary isn't something I have learned yet sadly. What I am looking to do with the responses is check if they are correct. My initial thought was to have another array of the answers to those questions. So if I used a for loop, and had another array of the same size, that would work?

Comment: @Wardy24 Yep! That sounds like it should. Let me know if you need some help doing that, and I can edit my answer with an example. But I'll let you try it first.

Comment: I understand how to write the for loop, but I am getting a little hung up on the rest. Would I do an if statement inside of the for loop? The if statement comparing the music questions to the answers I put in the other array? Thanks for the help dude! Very greatly appreciated

Comment: @Wardy24 No problem! So wait, if I understand you correctly, you're writing something like a quiz? Is that correct? So you ask questions, the user answers, then you test their answers against predefined expectations? I just want to make sure I'm not guiding you in the wrong direction. You can definitely have an `if` block inside of a loop, though, yeah.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly right. So with each user input, i need it to read it against the answers to check whether or not the answer was correct. Is there a way to loop that? Or do I have to write out each if statement. Sorry if these are basic questions, I am still quite new to it.

Comment: @Wardy24 No problem. We were all new to this at some point! I edited my answer to include what unfortunately might amount to the answer, so I hope you can read that and understand it. You clearly want to *learn* the stuff, which is great, but I think that code should be pretty self-explanatory. There are a few other approaches (like, for instance, if you wanted to summarize results at the end rather than show "correct" or "incorrect" for each answer), but this is an example.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I was really busy last night and had work early today.  Thanks a lot for the help, it really did make a difference.  The answer you gave was actually really helpful, but I definitely read and understood it, not just copy and paste. You helped quite a bit more than anyone else has so far, so again, thanks!

Comment: @Wardy24 No worries. I'm glad I could be of some help. Is there anything else I can clear up or help with?